# Product of three bounded linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A,B,C:X\rightarrow Y$ be bounded and (of course linear) operators. I want to examine if their product is also linear and bounded. What I have done:

\begin{align}
ABC(\lambda x + \mu y)&=AB[\lambda C x + \mu C y ]=A[\lambda (BC) x + \mu (BC) y ]\\
&=\lambda (ABC) x + \mu (ABC) y 
\end{align}
since the operators are linear. Furthermore,
\begin{align}
||(ABCx)||=\|A(BCx)\| \leq K_1 \|B(Cx)\| \leq K_1 K_2\|Cx\| \leq K_1K_2K_3 \|x\| = K^{'}||x||
\end{align}
proving that their product is bounded.

Am I correct?

Comment: You need the condition $X=Y$, otherwise the product $AB$ makes no sense.

Comment: @daw why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the right ideas, but you have a significant typo in your second set of equations.  You should instead write something like
$$
\|A(BCx)\| \leq K_1 \|B(Cx)\| \leq K_1 K_2\|Cx\| \leq K_1K_2K_3 \|x\|
$$
Otherwise, you're correct.